# Compilation fails: cannot find -lboost_thread

Tags: c++, boost

One of my projects uses `boost_thread`. But the build of this projects fails, because it could not find `boost_thread` (`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-d`). FYI: I am working on a 32bit CentOS system.

So, I build boost with this command:

```
./b2 --layout=tagged toolset=gcc variant=debug 
    link=shared threading=multi address-model=32 
    -sZLIB_SOURCE=$ZLIB_DIR --build-type=complete
```

But when boost is finished with compiling and linking, I do not see any `libboost_thread`. Can someone tell me, what I am missing here?

Comment: If you're using CentOS, there should be a standard package you can install. Try that first.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What if I do not want to use the standard package from my OS? I know, that there are packages which I could use, but I do not want that.

Comment: Then you can build it yourself, but then it won't end up in the standard location, but probably `/usr/local/lib` and you need to use the `-L` flag for the linker when building your project to tell it where to find the library.

Comment: The problem is not, that the path is not correct. The path is correct. But in that path, there is no `libboost_thread`.  And there is no such file in the `boost_1_60_0/stage/lib`

Comment: The error message says `boost_thread-d` is missing, not `boost_thread`. Check if there is a typo somewhere in your makefiles. Regarding your own build of Boost, see if there are errors in the build log.

Comment: Where can I find the build log?

Comment: It's the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution for my problem. First, I added parameter `-q` to the build command (which stops the build if an error occurs).

Then I got the message that the header file `quadmath.h` was not found. After some googling, I installed the packages `libquadmath` and `libquadmath-devel` (on CentOS) and started the build of `boost` again.